# Validate HTML form fields if it is specified with required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I created a JSP page and I have many forms each in different tabs. So I have added a single submit button common to all forms(So the button is outside of the <**form**> tag). On each tab, when the submit is clicked, the appropriate forms are being submitted using JQuery. In all forms some form fields are required. And I have specified those fields with the required attribute like the following

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label input-label" for="hostname">Host :
                    <span class="requiredField"> * </span>
            </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="inputstyle" name="hostname" placeholder="host" required="required" />
</div>
```

The problem is when I click on submit button, it does not validate fields which are required. If the submit button is inside the form, it's working. But I need common submit button. How to solve this?

I am just thinking in JQuery I am submitting form with form action value. So before submitting is it possible to call function to validate form by passing form ID and evaluate the required fields? If so, please help me to code.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

```
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-primary inputstyle" onclick="submitForm();">SUBMIT</button>
```

JQuery for this

```
function submitForm() {
            var $submitform=$('#formId').val();

            //validateForm($submitform); // I have not created this function.
            $('#'+$submitform).submit();
    }
```

Comment: which javascript? I havn't tried any form validation till yet. Now if I do not give input also, the form is submitting

Comment: I just created a function like that and passing the form id. But after that I don't know how to code to find the required fields.

Comment: I am using JSP. When the form is submitted, it calls the Struts action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate your data using client or server side scripts. You have asked for a javascript solution here, which is valid. As the javascript will prevent anything from being submitted unless the data is valid.

You need a switch or if statement to choose which form to submit. You'll need to have an identifier 
and this is algorithm:

AS you are using a form ID
You only have to validate a form if you require certain fields completed. getElementByID for the form id is perfect, use the if or switch to choose which form is to be validated and then submitted

eg if id 'lname1' (for form1) is not nothing then 
and use the javascript function validate() to check all fields of THAT form are filled.
You will then have to have error checks, if more than one form has been filled, of once one field in a form has input, the other forms are disabled.

You could also run the if statement- on whether or not the form has been disabled.

To tell you the truth, it would probably be easier and chance for less errors to have a submit button for each for,.

example names:

```
function Validate()
        {


        // create array containing textbox elements
        var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email'), document.getElementById('messagetxt')];

        var error;

        for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
        // loop through each element to see if value is empty
        {
            if(inputs[i].value == '')
            {
                error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                alert(error);
                return false;
                }
        }
     }


     <form onsubmit="return Validate();"  action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact1" id="contact1"  >


        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" />


        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" id="lname"/>

        <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email"  id="email"/>

      <textarea placeholder="Message" name="messagetxt" id="messagetxt"></textarea>

    </form>  

     <form onsubmit="return Validate();"  action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact2" id="contact2" >
 //insert form details

    </form>  

        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"  />
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yvytty/b3qdN/

If you need more feedback or clarity pls ask.

Comment: But still I have to right validate function for all the forms. I was thinking to have a common function validate all forms by just passing the form id

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have 2 forms (form1 and form 2) to submit on button click... you can call the following function on button click event.

```
function SubmitAllForms()
{
    document.forms.form1.submit();
    document.forms.form2.submit();
}
```

Comment: I am not submitting all the forms simultaneously. First I submit first form in first tab, its action process in Java using struts the come to second tab and there the next form. In JQuery I am submitting the form like this

`$('#'+$submitform).submit();` where `$submitform` is the form id of the current form I need to submit

Answer (score 1):

I think that below code will help you to solve your issue

HTML

```
   <form action="insertserverdata.php" id="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="userName">
         <input type="text" name="userPass">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

JS

```
 var formRules={userName:{required:true},userPass:{required:true}};

 $("#myForm").validate({rules:formRules});

 $("#myForm").submit(function(event){

 if(! $("#myForm").valid()){

   return;

 }

 });


//Also you can get your form fields by using below code

  var values = {};
  $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
     values[field.name] = field.value;
  });
```

Comment: So for all the forms I have to create function like this right?

Comment: Then I could do that without asking here. I am asking find the required fields in the submitting form and validate it

Comment: @ShijuKBabu now see the updated answer i think  this solves ur pbm

Answer (score 1):

ASSUMPTION: you click on tab, okay thats great you could create a hidden input and change it's value based on the tab you pressed lets illustrate more: you have form1,form2 and form3 on three tabs to toggle between so when you click on specific tab lets say tab1 which leads to form1 onclick you need to call method setVariable "which I made up" this method sets the value of your hidden input to let's say 1, example:

```
<div id="tab1" onclick="setVariable(1)">
```

now in you js you have this method:

```
function setVariable (value){
    document.getElementById('our hiddin input id').value= value;
}
```

now what? okay now it's time to validate onclick of your submit button you should call the method validateMyForm but which form?? well the form that have the same number as your hidden field watch that:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateMyForm(document.getElementById('hidden input').value)"/>
```

then in your js:

```
function validateMyForm(val){
    //use a switch or if-else to know which form you're validating and also which action should be submitted
}
```

that's pretty much the Idea goodluck